# ¿Cómo hago para formatear correctamente un documento desde Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-documentos

Estoy intentando reemplazar parte del contenido de un documento de Google con datos de una hoja de cálculos. Es un proceso que debo automatizar desde Google Script.

El problema lo tengo puntualmente en esta parte `body.replaceText('{{fecha}}', mesa[5]); //formatear fecha` ya que la fecha aparece en este formato `Thu Dec 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)`, y necesito que aparezca así; `Jueves, 3 de diciembre de 2020`. Lo mismo me sucede con la hora.

En la hoja de cálculos aparece como quiero, pero no logro darle formato en el documento...

Este es mi código:

```
const modeloDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1ibUdfZXMaXEe8zMtw-eMQ_gJn3I2OUkrJWJCP-ooz6M');
const folderPDFs = DriveApp.getFolderById('1o7FvXMlUeFV0wOvxwhbX-DZqqA0axiWb');
const folderx = DriveApp.getFolderById('1SjjQa446BeoQgFFFegrp9I7o_Bvv0jR9');


function buscarInfo() {
  var files = folderx.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
    var condicion;
    if (filename.indexOf('Libres')) {condicion = 'Libres'} else {condicion='Regulares'}
    
    var alumnos = ssheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(8, 1, ssheet.getLastRow(), 4).getValues();
    var mesa1 = ssheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
    var mesa2 = ssheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
    var mesa = mesa1[0].concat(mesa2[0]);
    
    Logger.log(alumnos);
    
    var nuevaCopiaDoc = modeloDoc.makeCopy(folderPDFs);
    var openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(nuevaCopiaDoc.getId());
    var body = openDoc.getBody();
    body.replaceText('{{profesortitular}}', mesa[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{espaciocurricular}}', mesa[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{regular}}', condicion);
    body.replaceText('{{fecha}}', mesa[5]); //formatear fecha
    body.replaceText('{{hora}}', mesa[6]);  //formatear hora
    body.replaceText('{{linkmeet}}', mesa[7]); //formatear URL
    body.appendTable(alumnos).setBorderWidth(0);
    
  }
}
```

UPDATE "HELP!"

Encontre una vuelta a mi problema. Grabé una macro en una de las hojas de cálculo, de tal manera que copio los valores en formato texto y luego los vuelvo a colocar (como texto) en sus casillas originales. De esta forma, DocumentApp recoge un STRING en lugar de un dato DATE.

```
    sheet.getRange('E5').activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TO_TEXT(A5)');
    sheet.getRange('A5').activate();
    sheet.getRange('E5').copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    sheet.getRange('E5').activate();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TO_TEXT(B5)');
    sheet.getRange('B5').activate();
    sheet.getRange('E5').copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

La solución parecía perfecta pero... BORRÓ LOS DATOS ORIGINALES DE TODAS LA PLANILLAS!!

No sé que hacer, salvo recuperar la versión previa de cada planilla en el Drive.
No encuentro un script para volver a la versión previa en bulk...

SOLUCIÓN (Más bien, parche)

Esto es lo que hice. Cumplió su función, pero me parece horrible:

```
    sheet.getRange('A5').copyTo(sheet.getRange('J5'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    sheet.getRange('J6').activateAsCurrentCell();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TO_TEXT(A5)');
    var date = sheet.getRange('J6').getValue().toString();
    sheet.getRange('A5').setValue(date);
    sheet.getRange('A5').setNumberFormat('@');
    
    sheet.getRange('B5').copyTo(sheet.getRange('K5'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    sheet.getRange('K6').activateAsCurrentCell();
    sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TO_TEXT(B5)');
    var date = sheet.getRange('K6').getValue().toString();
    sheet.getRange('B5').setValue(date);
    sheet.getRange('B5').setNumberFormat('@');
    sheet.getRange('A1').activate()
```

Comment: Lo que has agregado com UPDATE "HELP!" parece una pregunta diferente, deberías publicarla a aparte.

Comment: Hola @Rubén. No, por el contrario. Se trata del mismo asunto, pero abordado desde dos lugares diferentes. El error inicial estuvo en asumir que podía formatear el valor DATE desde Google Docs. Luego me di cuenta que debía convertir el valor DATE a STRING en la hoja de cálculos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu hoja de cálculo muestra la fecha en el formato que ocupas, en lugar de `getValue()` usa `getDisplayValue()` / en lugar de `getValues()`  usa `getDisplayValues()`